# Writing to a php array from javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm pretty new to both javascript and php and am having trouble getting something done.

I have an array form variable in PHP:

```
        <input type='hidden' id='results[]' name='results[]' value=''></input>
```

I want to put values in it through javascript and don't know how.

I'm trying something like the following:

```
                $("#results[index]").attr("value", "string");
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between client-side and server-side programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming)

Comment: `results[]` and `results[index]` are not the same ID. Give a real ID to each input.

Comment: But if I don't know how many items I'll have, how can I do this in advance?

Comment: The `name` attribute is used in PHP to process form fields, not the ID. So give your elements normal IDs and make sure they're unique

Comment: @WandaEmbar You're adding these via some sort of logic or loop, right? Keep track of the number you've output, and just do like `results_1`, `results_2`, and so on.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ajax_get_post.asp

Answer (score 1):

That's not PHP, that's HTML.

First, remove those brackets from the `id` as that might not even be valid (but is likely confusing the issue):

```
<input type='hidden' id='results' name='results[]' value=''></input>
```

And set the value with `val()`:

```
$("#results").val("string");
```

Everything that's happening here is client-side in HTML and JavaScript, PHP isn't involved here at all.

Comment: You're right. I'm using php though to get the result variables to another page. I want to put more than one variable in, that's why I made it an array. How can I do this?

Comment: @WandaEmbar: This is only a single `input` element, so it's only going to have a single value.  That value can be some sort of serialized string of an array, which you could de-serialize in your PHP code if you like.  There may be other ways to achieve what you're trying to do, but you aren't specifying anything about that in the question.

Comment: A serialized string! Thanks so much David. I could work with that! :)

Comment: @WandaEmbar If you want to have more than one value, you need to write more than one `<input>`.

Comment: Thanks Alvaro. The problem is that I don't know beforehand how many results I'll have. However, I'm working with a long string with delimiters now and the gorgeous explode method is putting it in an array for me. It's working like a charm. I appreciate all the help all of you gave!